# Brass wool versus steel wool

Tags: soldering

We're using this kind of solder sponge made of brass in our electronics course:

[image: Solder sponge]

One kid told me that he had seen this before. I wondered a bit, because they are all new to soldering. Finally he brought that thing into the class and it turned out to be steel wool, used in the kitchen.

[image: Steel wool]

Is it ok to use that instead? If not, why not?

Comment: Why didn't that question show up in the duplicates at the time I was writing the question?

Comment: Oh, the irony.  A fella named [Weller](https://www.weller-tools.com/professional/EUR/en/home) asking about soldering irons.

Comment: Duplicates happen. No big deal.

Comment: @JRE: I'm just asking about wool. If I need to ask about the soldering irons, I'll use a new account with a different name :-D